# ng-grid overlapping tables, need to set height correctly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ng-grid

I have two tables

```
<div ng-grid="table1"></div>

<div ng-grid="table2"></div>
```

Both tables have dynamically generated rows through an AJAX call on the angular side.

Thus, when the tables are rendered, Table 2 is not aware of the height of Table 1.

How do I make it so that Table 1 will "push" Table 2 down?

One idea I have is to be able to count the number of items in the JS side, then use Angular to modify the CSS on the fly (through a directive)..

Thanks,

Comment: What ruby-on-rails has to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has the same problem, I used ng-style() to dynamically change the height on the backend.